# jQuery toggle to display and hide content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, toggle

I have created show hide content script with jQuery but I don't want to slide content when toggle. Currently my content moving from left to right that I don't want.

My HTML:

```
<div id="menu-item-775">
  <a href="#collapse1">
    Contact
  </a>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" style="display:none">
  <div id="contact_main" style="width:100%; height:300px;">
    <div style="float:left; width:55%; color:#FFF; margin:4% 0 0 5%;">
      <div class="contact">
        <p>
          CONTACT 
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        FOR BOOKING & SPECIAL APPEARANCES
      </div>
      <div style="padding:">
        14 Tottenham Court Road
        London
        England
        W1T 1JY
      </div>
      <div>
        Phone: XXX / 555-3333
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; width:40%;">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item-775 a').click(function() {
        //get collapse content selector
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');

        //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                //change the button label to be 'Show'
                //toggle_switch.html('Show');
                } else {
                //change the button label to be 'Hide'
                //toggle_switch.html('Hide');
                }
        });
    });

});
```

Fiddle: [Sample](http://goo.gl/TWI7lH)

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) with [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) like,

```
$(collapse_content_selector).slideToggle(function () {
    $(this).is(':visible')? toggle_switch.text('Hide') : toggle_switch.text('Show');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ryA4F/)

Read [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing the animation piece of the toggle effect. Because you are providing a function for the parameter, it is animating the element. From the jQuery Doc (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

> When a duration, a plain object, or a single "complete" function is
>   provided, .toggle() becomes an animation method. **The .toggle() method
>   animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements
>   simultaneously.** When these properties reach 0 after a hiding
>   animation, the display style property is set to none to ensure that
>   the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

Because it's animating the width and height simultaneously, you get a diagonal animation appearance. For you, it looks like it's sliding right because the "right" text is floating to the right of the div. In reality, it's animating the height at the same time it animates the width. The "right" text is to the right of the div, but the div width, throughout the animation, is not it's full size yet. If you slow it down and add a background color you will see the diagonal animation clearly.

Perhaps one of the easiest solutions is to just use the fadeToggle method instead.

```
$(collapse_content_selector).fadeToggle(function() {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
        //change the button label to be 'Show'
            toggle_switch.html('Show');
        } else {
            //change the button label to be 'Hide'
            toggle_switch.html('Hide');
        }
});
```

Fiddle to show diagonal animation: http://jsfiddle.net/LDVXn/

Fiddle for solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cT4FB/

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, just replace .toggle() by .slideToggle() and it should do the trick.

```
$(collapse_content_selector).slideToggle(function() {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
        //change the button label to be 'Show'
        //toggle_switch.html('Show');
    } else {
        //change the button label to be 'Hide'
        //toggle_switch.html('Hide');
    }
});
```

Here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SjKMX/1/

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/SjKMX/5/)**

```
$('#menu-item-775 a').click(function() {
    $(this).text( this.textContent=='Show'?'Hide':'Show' );
    $(this.getAttribute('href')).slideToggle();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 $('#menu-item-775 a').click(function () {
    if($('#collapse1').is(":visible"))
    {
       $('#collapse1').slideUp("slow");
   }else
   {
        $('#collapse1').slideDown("slow");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this script

```
$('#menu-item-775 a').click(function() {
    if($(this).text( this.textContent=='Show'))
    {
        $(this).text( this.textContent='hide')
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).text( this.textContent='Show')
    }
    $(this.getAttribute('href')).slideToggle();   
});
```

your html code

```
<section class="round-border">
    <h2>jQuery toggle() to hide/show collapse content</h2>
    <div id="menu-item-775"> <a href="#collapse1">Show</a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" style="display:none">
        <div id="contact_main" style="width:100%; height:300px;">
            <div style="float:left; width:55%; color:#FFF; margin:4% 0 0 5%;">
                <div class="contact">
                    <p>CONTACT</p>
                </div>
                <div>FOR BOOKING & SPECIAL APPEARANCES</div>
                <div style="padding:">14 Tottenham Court Road London England W1T 1JY</div>
                <div>Phone: XXX / 555-3333</div>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; width:40%;">Right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```